# Force deletion of singleton in test code that was created with dispatch_once

Tags: objective-c

I'm writing some unit test code for a model class and want to simulate the behavior of the class during app exit and relaunch. I could achieve this by deleting and re-allocing the object, however its a singleton and thus the following code doesn't have the desired effect:

```
+ (id) sharedInstance
{
    static MyModel *singleton = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;

    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^ {
        singleton = [[MyModel alloc] initSharedInstance];
    });
    return singleton;
}


// Test code:
    MyModel* gModel = [MyModel sharedInstance];
    ... tests
    gModel = nil;
    gModel = [MyModel sharedInstance];
    ... more tests
```

Is there a neat solution so I can delete/recreate the object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
static MyModel *singleton = nil;
static dispatch_once_t onceToken;

+ (instancetype) sharedInstance
{
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^ {
        if (singleton==nil){
            singleton = [[MyModel alloc] initSharedInstance];
        }
    });
    return singleton;
}

+(void)setSharedInstance:(MyModel *)instance {
    onceToken = 0;
    singleton = instance;
}
```

Nil it:

```
[MyModel setSharedInstance:nil];
```

Note that you can also set it to an arbitrary class to mock it.

```
[MyModel setSharedInstance:someMock];
```

Comment: Note that this is not thread safe, since the re-initialization of the once token does not have a memory barrier

Answer (score 1):

sure something like this would be fine for unit testing, you can turn it off for prod:

```
static MyModel *singleton = nil;

+ (id) sharedInstance
{   
   if(!singleton)
    {
        singleton = [self new];
    }
    return singleton;
}
+ (void)resetSingleton
{
    [singlelton release];
    singleton = nil;
}
```