# Possible to set singleton back to nil?

Tags: ios, singleton, null

I have implemented a singleton object using the regular pattern. My question is: is it possible to set this object back to nil, so that on a later called to [MySingleton sharedInstance] the object gets re-initialised?

```
// Get the shared instance and create it if necessary.
+ (MySingleton *)sharedInstance {

    static dispatch_once_t pred;
    static MySingleton *shared = nil;
    dispatch_once(&pred, ^{
        shared = [[MySingleton alloc] init];
    });
    return shared;
}

// We can still have a regular init method, that will get called the first time the     Singleton is used.
- (id)init 
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
    // Work your initialising magic here as you normally would

    }
    return self;
}
```

My guess is that

```
MySingleton *shared = [MySingleton sharedInstance];
shared = nil;
```

only sets the local pointer `shared` to `nil`. After all, `shared` is declared as `static`.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Your assumption about the local reference is correct, it won't affect your singleton.

To be able to reinitialize the singleton you need to move the static variable out of your method, so it's accessible by the whole class.

```
static MySingleton *sharedInstance = nil;
// Get the shared instance and create it if necessary.
+ (MySingleton *)sharedInstance {
    if (sharedInstance == nil) {
        sharedInstance = [[MySingleton alloc] init];
    }
    return sharedInstance;
}

+ (void)resetSharedInstance {
    sharedInstance = nil;
}
```

Note that you cannot use `dispatch_once` anymore, since your singleton needs obviously to be created multiple times. If you only ever call this singleton from your UI (and therefore only from the main thread), then the sample above is fine.

If you need access from multiple threads you need to put a lock around the `+sharedInstance` and `+resetSharedInstance` method, e.g.

```
+ (id)sharedInstance {
    @synchronized(self) {
        if (sharedInstance == nil) {
            sharedInstance = [[MySingleton alloc] init];
        }
        return sharedInstance;
    }
}

+ (void)resetSharedInstance {
    @synchronized(self) {
        sharedInstance = nil;
    }
}
```

This is quite a bit slower than the `dispatch_once` variant, but in practice it won't matter usually.

Answer (score 5):

Yeah, but your singleton's `sharedInstance` method defines it as a `static` inside that method, and your final code sample is just setting a local variable (coincidentally also called `shared`) to `nil`, leaving the `static` inside `sharedInstance` unaltered. Thus you are just `nil`-ing a local pointer, not changing the `static` inside `sharedInstance`.

If you want to do what you're asking, you'll have to pull the `static` variable, `shared`, out of the `sharedInstance` method (and presumably write some `reset` method to `nil` it). Your `sharedInstance` method also can no longer rely upon `dispatch_once`, but rather have to check to see if that `static` is `nil` or not.

Answer (score 3):

I did this. I'm not sure if it's the best way but it seemed to work fine.

```
static dispatch_once_t pred;
static MySingleton *shared = nil;

+(MySingleton *)sharedInstance {
        dispatch_once(&pred, ^{
            shared = [[MySingleton alloc] init];
        });
        return shared;
    }

+(void)clearSharedInstance {

       shared = nil;
       pred = nil;
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't reset the predicate of dispatch_once. See here for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10930044/possible-to-reset-state-of-dispatch-once-in-unit-test-to-make-them-run-again

Comment: @Fönsi It seems I should set pred to 0 instead of nil. Correct?

Comment: Yes and no. You are correct in that `dispatch_once_t` is a `long` and therefore you should use `0` instead of `nil`. But the bigger issue I wanted to highlight is that the concept of "resetting" the dispatch once predicate is dangerous.

Comment: For example there is a race condition inherent in the reset, where you could be resetting the predicate but at the same time someone is already calling your `+sharedInstance` method again.

Comment: Well, I have to reset it somehow. Do you have a better way?

Comment: I recommend you use plain old locking using `@synchronize` instead and provide a reset method. `dispatch_once` is not intended to be executed multiple times (hence the name ;-) ).

Comment: What about something like the second answer from here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16491326/force-deletion-of-singleton-in-test-code-that-was-created-with-dispatch-once

Comment: Nevermind, I figured out how to solve my problem without ever resetting the singleton :)