# Initialise and use threadsafe static object in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, thread-safety, grand-central-dispatch

This method will be called from multiple threads and returns a `static` dictionary which will only be read and not written to by the calling threads. The initial values are dynamic and thus the internal implementation is an `NSMutableDictionary`.

From what I understand, since the assignment to `dictionary` is **not** a `static` initialiser and its state is also further mutated, the `@synchronized` block is required before it's returned to ensure the initialised values are seen by all calling threads. Is this correct or should I remove the `@synchronized` and set a memory barrier as the last line of the `dispatch_once` block?

I only need to ensure that the initially assigned values are visible to all caller threads.

```
+ (NSDictionary *)threadSafeMethod {
    static NSMutableDictionary *dictionary;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
        [dictionary setValue:dynamicValue1 forKey:@"key1"];
        [dictionary setValue:dynamicValue2 forKey:@"key2"];
    });

    @synchronized(dictionary) {
        return dictionary;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@synchronized is basically a mutex on the lock object.

The way you use it protects only the return of the object and not it's use. Thus, the threads will block each other to obtain the dictionary pointer.

Update: as your object is immutable on the outside, the protection is not needed there.

I doubt that @synchronize is of any use at all in your case, just leave it as is. Initialization will be done once, others are blocked until the first in line finished the block. 
Then everybody get's his pointer to the dictionary created, so all threads read the same dictionary and there is no blocking any more.

Comment: Callers can only read the dictionary, not write to it. I just need to ensure that the initial construction and values are visible to all caller threads. It also needs to be lazy initialised on the first call to the method.

Comment: Then synchronizing the read is basically not needed as soon as the dispatch has run. If I get your construction right, you fear a situation where a thread enters initialization, while another reads the dictionary. then you have the problem that there may be a thread running into the function before the dispatched block ran and you need to check nil on the return. if possible maybe init the dict before spawning the threads? then you need no synch at all.

Comment: No, I know that dispatch_once blocks other callers. But even once it's complete, how is the memory it modifies visible to other threads? I cannot find any documentation that it imposes a memory barrier. The block won't run again in thread #2, but it doesn't mean thread #2 can see what was assigned in the block when it executed in thread #1.

Comment: ok, I read dispatch once docs. why do you fear a synchronization issue at all?

Comment: `dispatch_once` only states that it runs once. If you call the function repeatedly from the same thread, the block will only execute the first time. However, if you call it from multiple threads, what is the guarantee that the assignment is **visible** to the second thread? The block won't **run** a second time, but the assignment is not guaranteed to be visible unless the first run had a memory barrier after assignment.

Comment: My point is, even **after** initialization is done and the pointer is assigned, the pointer will **still** appear to be `nil` to a second thread unless there was a memory barrier after it was assigned in the first thread.

Comment: you wont get past dispatch_once until it completes the block with the first caller, all waiting threads will skip the block and receive the pointer to the dict initialized.

Comment: Even after the dictionary is initialised in thread #1, and thread #2 skips the dispatch_once block, thread #2 will think the dictionary is `nil`. There has to be a memory barrier in thread #1 to guarantee that it's instantly visible to thread #2 even after the initialisation has fully completed. Are you aware of the concept of memory (non)visibility across threads? There has to be a memory barrier. Is there some source that states that dispatch_once does this?

Comment: dispatch_once() has some very clever (arguably overly clever) tricks to safely avoid the barrier once initialization is complete. See http://opensource.apple.com/source/libdispatch/libdispatch-84.5.3/src/once.c (note that some of the implementation is inline in once.h)

Comment: Yes, they live in the same memory. Thread one will see all memory of thread 2. that is the main difference to processes, they are not seperated. The code sequence you wrote is an ios singleton initializer pattern.

Comment: @Catfish_Man In your answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/16491496/274972 you said the predicate variable isn't threadsafe. Is that applicable here? Is *everything* inside the `dispatch_once` block visible to all other threads?

Comment: @thst No, they only share the same memory address, but are potentially read from different physical locations (CPU core 1's cache, core 2's cache, RAM). Without a memory barrier or some other mechanism, two threads will see different values. With a single thread it doesn't matter where it's stored, but with two threads it does.

Comment: In my answer there I was referring to 'onceToken = 0;' as the unsafe part.

Comment: @Locutus If the compiler doesnt take care of such things, assembler is an option. Did you ever run into such issues in objc?

Comment: It's the most fundamental principle of thread safety in every language... You have to use constructs that enforce memory barriers and prevent re-ordering where ever required.

Comment: @Locutus My point is not that you need to be aware of thread safety, my point was, that I am not the role to take care of low-level caching and memory location issues, when I am using a high(er) level language like objc - here I expect the compiler to do this. Making sure that object access is thread-safe in the semantics of the language and managing multi-threading according to specs (UI specials) is my responsibility. But I think this is not the right place for discussion, and I will be happy to continue with you at another place if you think I am making my life too simple here.